# Output does not correnspond with source

Tags: php, post

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

gives

```
['content'] = string....
```

and `echo $_POST['content']`

displays the right code in browser
but in both cases the source only displays a notice

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: content in<b>C:\wamp\www\php\prosessComment.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br /> array(0) {}
```

and the apparently missing variable. I can do all sorts of things with it, but when I try to put it in a query, it comes out blank.

Comment: What does line 6 look like? Could you be misspelling `$_POST`, eg `$POST['content']`

Comment: I don't get it, too. Your example is not clear. Please edit.

Answer (score 0):

That error message indicates *the variable may not be set* - so, I would try double checking whether that is the case by using the following. If it prints "ERROR!", you will need to look at how you are setting the variable:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['content'])) { 
   $_POST['content'] = "ERROR!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Note: you will need to place this before your *echo* line obviously